# const auto std::initializer_list difference between Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, stl, clang

I am trying to understand what the correct behavior of C++11 should be when combining initialization lists and `const auto`. I am getting different behavior between GCC and Clang for the following code and would like to know which is the correct one:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::initializer_list<int> l1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    const auto l2 = { 1, 2, 3 };

    std::cout << "explicit: " << typeid(l1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "auto:     " << typeid(l2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Compiled with g++ the output is:

```
explicit: St16initializer_listIiE
auto:     St16initializer_listIKiE
```

While the clang++ compiled version produces:

```
explicit: St16initializer_listIiE
auto:     St16initializer_listIiE
```

It seems that GCC is turning the `auto` line into a `std::initializer_list<const int>` while Clang produces `std::initializer_list<int>`. The GCC version creates a problem when I use it to initialize a `std::vector`. So the following works under Clang but produces a compiler error for GCC.

```
// Compiles under clang but fails for GCC because l4
std::vector<int> v2 { l2 };
```

If GCC is producing the correct version then it seems to suggest that the various STL containers should be extended to include another list initializer overload for these cases.

Note: this behavior seems to be consistent across multiple versions of GCC (4.8, 4.9, 5.2) and Clang (3.4 and 3.6).

Comment: Can you check `std::vector<int> v2 ( l2.begin(), l2.end() );`  (It should work)  Considering this, perhaps initializer lists of any type that implicitly converts should be accepted, even if the deduction changes.  On the other hand, this might result in the initializer list constructor hiding other constructors more often.

Comment: Yes `std::vector<int> v2 (l2.begin(), l2.end()); does indeed work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GCC bug. [dcl.spec.auto]/p7 (quoting N4527):

> When a variable declared using a placeholder type is initialized,
>   [...] the deduced return type or variable type is determined from the
>   type of its initializer. [...] Otherwise, let `T` be the declared type
>   of the variable [...]. If the placeholder is the `auto`
>   *type-specifier*, the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument deduction. If the initialization is
>   *direct-list-initialization* [...]. [...] Otherwise, obtain `P` from `T` by replacing the occurrences of `auto` with either a new invented
>   type template parameter `U` or, if the initialization is
>   *copy-list-initialization*, with `std::initializer_list<U>`. Deduce a value for `U` using the rules of template argument deduction from a
>   function call (14.8.2.1), where `P` is a function template parameter
>   type and the corresponding argument is the initializer [...]. If the
>   deduction fails, the declaration is ill-formed. Otherwise, the type
>   deduced for the variable or return type is obtained by substituting
>   the deduced `U` into `P`.

Thus, in `const auto l2 = { 1, 2, 3 };`, deduction is performed as if for the function template

```
template<class U> void meow(const std::initializer_list<U>);
```

given the call `meow({1, 2, 3})`.

Now consider the const-less case `auto l3 = { 1, 2, 3 };` (which GCC correctly deduces as `std::initializer_list<int>`). Deduction in this case is performed as if for the function template

```
template<class U> void purr(std::initializer_list<U>);
```

given the call `purr({1, 2, 3})`.

Since top-level cv-qualification of function parameters are ignored, it should be obvious that the two deduction should yield the same type.

---

[temp.deduct.call]/p1:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it `P`) with the type of the
>   corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below.
>   If `P` is a dependent type, removing references and cv-qualifiers from
>   `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P'>` [...] for some `P'` [...] and
>   the argument is a non-empty initializer list (8.5.4), then deduction
>   is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking
>   `P'` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element
>   as its argument.

Deducing `P'` (which is `U`) against `1`, `2`, or `3`, all literals of type `int`, obviously yields `int`.

Comment: I don't see how the *top-level cv-qualification* is at issue here, the problem is `initializer_list<const int>` and not `const initializer_list<int>`

Comment: Does `auto l3 = { 1, 2, 3 };` NOT deduce the same template parameter (`const int`) in gcc?

Comment: Correct `auto l3 = { 1,2,3};` does NOT deduce the same template parameters as `const auto l2 = {1,2,3};` in gcc. When I try it `typeid(l3).name()` produces `St16initializer_listIiE`.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 6):

There is a gcc bug report [wrong auto deduction from braced-init-list](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63149) about this and similar cases and Richard Smith  indicates it is a gcc bug:

> Even simpler testcase:
>
> ```
> #include <initializer_list>
> const auto r = { 1, 2, 3 };
> using X = decltype(r);
> using X = const std::initializer_list<int>;
> ```
>
> fails because `decltype(r)` is deduced as `const std::initializer_list<const int>` rather than `const std::initializer_list<int>`.

The section of the draft C++ standard would be section `7.1.6.4` *[dcl.spec.auto]* which says:

> When a variable declared using a placeholder type is initialized, or a return statement occurs in a function
>   declared with a return type that contains a placeholder type, the deduced return type or variable type
>   is determined from the type of its initializer. [...] Let T be the declared type of the variable or return type of the function. If the
>   placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type is determined using the rules for template argument
>   deduction. [...] Otherwise, obtain P from T by replacing the occurrences of auto with either a
>   new invented type template parameter U or, if the initializer is a braced-init-list, with std::initializer_-
>   list. Deduce a value for U using the rules of template argument deduction from a function call (14.8.2.1),
>   where P is a function template parameter type and the initializer is the corresponding argument [...] [ Example:
>
> ```
> auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // decltype(x1) is std::initializer_list<int>
> auto x2 = { 1, 2.0 }; // error: cannot deduce element type
> ```
>
> —end example ] [ Example:
>
> ```
> const auto &i = expr;
> ```
>
> The type of i is the deduced type of the parameter u in the call f(expr) of the following invented function template:
>
> ```
> template <class U> void f(const U& u);
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and link to the bug report.