# Portability of auto keyword

Tags: c++

I'm a bit new to use of the auto keyword.  The project I work on only recently switched to using compilers that all support it.  I want to make a code change that I can easily test on only one of the many compilers it will need to be correct on (I'm testing one ICC version.  It needs to be correct in multiple versions each of ICC, GCC, and MSVC).  So I want to be sure my understanding of this use of auto is correct.

The original code was:
`f_y( f_x() );`
where f_x() returns a `const&` to something and f_y takes a `const&` to that same thing.  I need to change the code to copy/modify the thing if and only if it really needs to be copied and modified.  It may be much too big to copy when it doesn't need to be copied.  So I wrote:

```
auto const& c=f_x();
if ( c.size()==1 && c[0].second<0.0 )
{
   auto c_copy = c;
   c_copy[0].second = 1.0;
   f_y( c_copy );
}
else
   f_y( c );
```

I'm curious whether the `const` is really needed on my first use of `auto` or whether the compiler deduces that because f_x() returns a `const&`.  But even if not needed, I'd want it there to make my code understandable as long as none of the compilers are confused by it.

Mainly I'm asking about the second auto.  The one compiler I've tested makes that call the copy constructor of the referenced object type (rather than copy just the reference).  I'm pretty sure that is the only possible meaning of that code.  But I want a bit more confidence that all the versions of ICC, GCC and MSVC that understand auto at all will understand it that way.

BTW, the data type of `c[0].first` is known to the compiler, but not known (nor relevant) to the programmer at that point in the source code.

Comment: There are cases where current compiler do different things with auto such as: [Different compiler behavior for expression: auto p {make_pointer()};](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31301369/1708801) and [const auto std::initializer_list difference between Clang and GCC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32515183/1708801) but I feel like most of those cases are edge cases where the standard is evolving or bugs. For most cases auto should behave the same way for each compiler.

Comment: You don't have to have the `const` on the first one. That second one *should* make a copy, by the standard. But if you have to cater to outdated compilers and their bugs, then you'll need to test it on all those compilers you want to support.

Comment: @Yakk not to the specific code but I read the question as being a more general question on the portability of auto.

Comment: @Shafik  I was only asking about the specific usage in my question.  But I also will continue expanding my use of `auto` elsewhere in this project, so I appreciate the warning.  I will pretty consistently be able to test on fewer compilers than I need to support.  So I need to understand any important differences between what works and what the standard promises.

Comment: Ah sadly, if all the compilers you use claim they support C++11, then they should implement auto consistently for your case.  But, bugs are regularly found in many of the compilers, so you still cannot eliminate having to test each change you make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auto` removes references and top-level cv-qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`).

The type of `c` is `something const&` and it would be the same even if you wrote `auto& c = f_x()` (the same situation as `v5` on slide 15 of Scott Meyers' ["Type Deduction and Why You Care"](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf)) so you don't need a `const` there.

The type of `c_copy` is `something` (note: no `const` even though the RHS is a const reference; same as `v3` on the same slide) , that's why `c_copy = c` invokes the copy constructor.