# Deducing const from operator T &()

Tags: c++, c++11

Issue is that different compiler's produces different output (clang/gcc) and so that makes me think that this usage is undefined behavour. However my goal is to deduce `const` when assigning reference.

Output with:
clang-3.6 -> `not const`
gcc-4.8.4 -> `const`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct AnyReference {

    template <typename RT> AnyReference(RT &a_var) : _ptr(&a_var) {}

    template <typename T> operator T &() const
    {
        if (std::is_const<T>::value) {
            std::cout << "const\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "not const\n";
        }
        return *reinterpret_cast<T *>(_ptr);
    }
    void *_ptr;
};

int main()
{
    int i(5);
    AnyReference a(i);
    const int &c = a;
}
```

Comment: I let you read this following post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515183/const-auto-stdinitializer-list-difference-between-clang-and-gcc

Comment: Have you considered providing both `operator T&` and `operator const T&` ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt No I have not,  but it is great solution! It works as expected.

Comment: Doesn't this violated the strict aliasing rule? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility based on idea of Ben Voight

```
struct AnyReference {

    template <typename RT> AnyReference(RT &a_var) : _ptr(&a_var) {}

    template <typename T> operator T &() const { return operatorTand<T>(); }

    template <typename T> operator const T &() const
    {
        return operatorTand<const T>();
    }

  private:
    template <typename T> T &operatorTand() const
    {
        if (std::is_const<T>::value) {
            std::cout << "const\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "not const\n";
        }
        return *reinterpret_cast<T *>(_ptr);
    }

    void *_ptr;
};
```